# Cleaning messy data

Tags: data-cleaning, analysis

I have a .xlsx sheet and have been trying to clean text data from a list of different exporters who write their product descriptions differently. However, each row has a set of keywords that I would like to extract. I will show some examples below:
[image: The keyword in this is GROUPER]
[image: CUTTLEFISH]
To extract these keywords I wrote the following script on python:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def clean_text(text):
    # Remove special characters and numbers
    text = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', ' ', text)
    
    # Convert to lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    
    return text

def extract_seafood_keywords(text, seafood_terms):
    seafood_keywords = []
    
    # Tokenize the text into words
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    
    # Find seafood keywords based on token matching and spelling variations
    for term in seafood_terms:
        for word in words:
            if term in word.lower() or term.replace(' ', '') in word.lower():
                seafood_keywords.append(word)
    
    return seafood_keywords

# Read the data from Excel
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/xyz/abc/Test_For_Cleaning.xlsx', sheet_name='EXPORT')

# List of seafood-related keywords
seafood_terms = ['grouper', 'fish', 'shrimp', 'crab', 'squid', 'vannamei', 'brown', 'white', 'poovalan', 'karikkady', 'karikady', 'octopus', 'black tiger', 'mackerel', 'reef cod', 'lobster', 'reefcod', 'cuttle fish', 'ribbon fish', 'tuna']

# Clean and extract seafood keywords from each data item
seafood_keywords_list = []

for item in df['Product']:
    cleaned_text = clean_text(item)
    seafood_keywords = extract_seafood_keywords(cleaned_text, seafood_terms)
    seafood_keywords_list.append(seafood_keywords)

# Add the extracted seafood keywords as a new column to the DataFrame
df['Seafood Keywords'] = seafood_keywords_list

# Write the updated DataFrame back to Excel
df.to_excel('C:/Users/xyz/abc/Test_For_Cleaning.xlsx', sheet_name='EXPORT', index=False)
```

The above script helps to an extent but it highlights keywords twice if it is in the product description and also doesn't account for spaces:
For example, it extracts the keyword fish and any word that preceeds fish without space but won't extract the keyword if there is a space for example: RIBBON FISH or CUTTLE FISH

There are also product descriptions with spacing errors:
[image: It's written as CUTTLEF ISH]

The sheet has over 5,00,000 rows and every exporter has written it differently, even though the product is the same.

I tried to clean it on excel itself by using the * wildcard but it takes away some important information.

Maybe I am approaching this problem in the wrong way. If you guys have a better solution, I am more than willing to give it a go.

Tried to find and replace it in Excel but lost important information.
Wrote a Python code but extraction isn't satisfactory.

EDIT: can't attach my excel sheet here, so here is a screenshot of some sample data

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

Comment: Supply some data that people can work with.